# Как создать некоторое количество параграфов в цикле записать их в переменную? React.js

Tags: reactjs

```js
let result = for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
   <p>Привет</p>
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const result = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    result.push(<p>Привет</p>);
}
```